# How to create a search bar in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, and I'm working on a small project that uses a search bar to find data that I've gotten from my database.

The code that I tried is below:

```
function AcceptedOffers() {

    const buyerId=(localStorage.getItem("userId"));
    console.log(buyerId);

    const [offers, setOffers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        getAllOffers();
    }, []);

    const getAllOffers = async () => {
        await axios.get(`/viewPendingSellerOffers`)
            .then ((response)=>{
                const allNotes=response.data.existingOffers;
                setOffers(allNotes);
            })
            .catch(error=>console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
    }
    console.log(offers);

    const filterData = (offersPara, searchKey) => {
        const result = offersPara.filter(
            (offers) =>
                offers?.value.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey) ||
                offers?.quantity.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)
        );
        setOffers(result);
    };

    const handleSearchArea = (e) => {
        const searchKey = e.currentTarget.value;

        axios.get(`/viewPendingSellerOffers`).then((res) => {
            if (res?.data?.success) {
                filterData(res?.data?.existingOffers, searchKey);
            }
        });
    };

    return(
        <div className="posts-b">
            <div className="posts__container-b">
                <h1>Accepted Offers</h1>
                <div className="search_box-b">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="What are you looking for?" onChange={handleSearchArea}></input>
                    <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
                </div>
                <main className="grid-b">
                    {offers.map((offer,index)=> {
                        if(offer.status==='accepted' && offer.buyerId===buyerId)
                            return (
                                <article>
                                    <div className="text-b">
                                        <h3>Post ID: {index + 1}</h3>
                                        <p>Quantity (Kg): {offer.quantity}</p>
                                        <p>Unit Price (Rs): {offer.value}</p>
                                        <p>Expiry Date: {moment(offer.expiryDate).fromNow()}</p>
                                        <p>Collecting Date: {moment(offer.collectingDate).fromNow()}</p>
                                        <p>Offer Gives: {moment(offer.offerCreatedAt).fromNow()}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </article>
                            );
                    })}
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AcceptedOffers;
```

From the first API call, I get a length 9 array of objects. This image shows the data that I got from the first API call.

[image: Results of first API call]

Then I mapped these data using a map function. Then I created a search function like the above code and try to map the search results in the same component. But when I type a search field as input then I got an error that says 'Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): offers.value.toLowerCase is not a function'. I've been through a bunch of tutorials, and I'm not exactly sure how to solve this issue.

Can anyone help me with this please to solve this problem? Any other comments on the code are also welcome. I'm here to learn.

Thank you!

Comment: You can't lower-case a number (In your data `value: 1`), so `toLowerCase` is unnecessary, and once that's removed, `includes` is also not a function on a number.

Comment: @DBS I removed `toLowerCase()` this part and try like this `offers?.value.includes(searchKey) || offers?.quantity.includes(searchKey)` but then also I get this error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): offers.value.includes is not a function`

Comment: I edited the original comment regarding `includes` (You may need to refresh the page to see it) But it very much sounds like you are expecting a string `value`, are you sure your API is returning the correct data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that offers.value is an integer and you are trying to use it as a string(toLowerCase and includes are functions applicable on strings). So to use them just change  offers.value to a string and proceed as usual. So your filterData function will look as follows -

```
const filterData = (offersPara, searchKey) => {
        const result = offersPara.filter(
            (offers) =>
                offers?.value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchKey) ||
                offers?.quantity.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)
        );
        setOffers(result);
    };
```

Comment: yes this works for me. I understand now what the problem was. Appreciate your help!